# jQuery bootstrap tabs not working in custom modal (not bootstrap modal but my own version)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs on a custom modal (my own version). The tabs open when clicked the first time the modal is opened, but no longer work the second time the modal is opened.

This is the HTML code for the tabs :

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->    
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am doing is  :

I have a button in my page, when clicked on it, a modal (like Lightbox) will open with the tabs in it.

The first time it is opened, the tabs are working fine; when tabs are clicked, respective content is displayed. But when it is closed and opened again, the tabs are *not* working; when the tabs are clicked, the respective data is not being displayed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Can you include the modal and button on a jsFiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/HQ7jr/

Comment: Can you post a test case or your full page markup? Its hard to diagnose something like this blindly. Also, what js scripts are you loading in your header and in what order?

Comment: I think closing the modal calls an `empty()` or `remove()` so it may be deleting your tabs from the DOM.  Double check to make sure they are still there after closing the modal.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be impossible to troubleshoot this without looking at *your* modal code, which is almost certainly part of the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I am dynamically adding elements to DOM, when button clicked,but I am not removing elements when CLOSE clicked, So,deleting the element after close is clicked is the solution .

Comment: Did you just answer your own question? If so, please mark this as the answer.